# Edge Histogram Descriptor

Tags: opencv, image-processing, feature-descriptor

I'm developing a software with OpenCv Library , my software is based on a paper about the multispectral stereo odometry. After edge extraction, from the image , i have to compute for each extracted feature the edge histogram descriptor.
From the paper:

"The spatial component of the descriptor is obtained as follows:

• Select a region of P × P pixels centered at the keypoint
of interest from the edge map.

• Divide the region into 16 (4 × 4) subregions.

• Compute local edge histograms for each subregion where
five bins are used to categorize an edge: horizontal,
vertical, 45◦ diagonal, 135◦ diagonal, and isotropic (no
orientation).

The resulting histogram vector formed of 80 bins (4 × 4 × 5)
is then normalized. "

My question is: if the keypoint is on the border of the edgeMap, my window (PxP) is out of bound for every P>=3 . Some paper reccomended to use P=100.
The same problem occurs also if the keypoint is near to the border.

How should i proceed?